# Java - socket.isConnected returns true to ANY ip address using port 80

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I am trying to establish communication with a device on my local network via the use of `Socket`, and verify the connection using the `Socket.isConnected()` method - seems simple enough, but I am getting some strange behavior.

Currently, I instantiate an unconnected socket with the no-arg `Socket()` constructor, and then, when ready, connect to the server (which is on port 80 for the device). Here is a snippet of the code:

```
deviceSocket = new Socket();
...
SocketAddress deviceSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(hostName, portNum);
deviceSocket.connect(deviceSocketAddress);
if (deviceSocket.isConnected()){
     System.out.println("Connected to "+hostName+":"+portNum);
}
```

As mentioned, the `portNum` that I must connect to on the device is 80, but regardless of the `hostName` that is provided, it **always** returns `true`. If I give an ip address of 10.0.1.115 (which is the address of the device), I get the same result as when I provide 10.0.1.114, or even something bogus like 13.2.5.2.

I've already done some research and have found that the `Socket.isConnected()` method will return `true` if the socket has ever been successfully connected, but that is not my issue, I've made sure that in each case I am starting with a brand-new unconnected socket.

I decided to take my issues to telnet, in which I noticed something very peculiar. If the command `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80` is issued in the command prompt, it **always** opens a blank page, which hangs for a while and then exits back to command prompt, rather than giving the appropriate error message (assuming the endpoint really doesn't exist)

```
Connecting to 13.2.5.2... Could not open connection to the host, on port 82: Connect failed
```

(Also, something else strange, using port 81 behaves the same way, it is only when I used 82, or another random port, that the connection failed)

So I think I've stumbled upon an interesting issue, but we'll see soon enough...

Thanks in advance for any and all replies!

-M

Comment: ports 1 through 1023 are reserved.

Comment: I see this answer almost everywhere I go if ports are discussed, and it bears no significance. Ports 1 through 1023 are well known ports but are not magically off-limits, otherwise HTTP (which operates on port 80) wouldn't be what it is. It is important to note however that it is typical for certain privileges are needed for these ports, but they are certainly not incapable of being used.

Comment: Also, even if the ports were indeed off-limits, then I believe the problem would be flipped where Socket.isConnected() would always return false. Thanks for the answer, but please consider the nature of the issue first.

Comment: Have you tried firing up wireshark and inspecting the traffic?

Comment: Slightly OT but calling `Socket.isConnected()` in the next line after `new Socket(SocketAddress)` is pointless. If the socket didn't connect, it would have thrown a `ConnectException` and you don't get to the next line. If you're at the next line, it's connected.

Comment: @EJP, that would be correct if I had been connecting to the socket via the use of the `new Socket(SocketImpl impl)` constructor, however I am using the bare constructor `new Socket()`, and am then using the `Socket.connect(SocketAddress sockAddr)` method to connect to the socket, which only throws an `IOException`.

Comment: @nsfyn55 - yes, I have indeed. Unfortunately, it hasn't yielded anything interesting, but maybe I am not as savvy with Wireshark as I need to be. I've set the filter to `ip.addr == 10.0.1.115` (the ip address of the actual device) to inspect the traffic when I run the telnet command, and indeed there is traffic shown. But, when setting the filter to `ip.addr == 10.0.1.114`, there is nothing to be seen in Wireshark, yet telnet seemingly connects to some "ghost host".. is there a chance it is using the loopback interface, and is there an easy way to monitor that traffic w/Wireshark? Thanks again

Comment: @MandM It is also true of calling `isConnected()` the line after `connect()`, as you are doing here. It is pointless. The code would be unreachable if the socket wasn't connected. And `ConnectException` extends `IOException.`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this behavior but here's a guess.

Your firewall allows port 80 (http) and 81 (often used as a http alternate). These ports try, then fail to connect after a timeout. Other ports that are not open in the firewall (like 82) are rejected immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems somewhat probable, but I tend towards thinking that it would be strange for telnet to not return with a "failure to connect" when an endpoint is given that doesn't exist, even if the port is allowed through the firewall.