# Java socket "successfully" connect to any IP on port 80

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to open a socket to a remote server, but I want to get an exception thrown if the other side is not responding. For some reason, any IP which I try with PORT 80 seems to "connect" even if it's a completely random IP.

I'll try to convey the issue with an example.

This will timeout and raise an exception:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4", 81), SOME_TIMEOUT_CONST);
```

On the other hand, the following will continue normally as if it connected successfully:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4", 80), SOME_TIMEOUT_CONST);
```

I can't seem to figure out the reason for that.

If this is the expected behavior, how can I check that in case 2 it did not actually connect?

**Edit:** I ran the same code on a friend's pc, and both cases timed out and raised an exception. So it's probably something with my Mac. No idea what...

Comment: I believe port `80` is used by web servers as a standard, but I'm not knowledgeable in the area; nor do I know if that has any bearing on what you're seeing.

Comment: Interesting. According to [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10625976/669576) with no accepted answer, it could be your firewall.  Also found [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1147243) on the Oracle forum from 2009 - also unanswered - that blames it on Vista.